# Avoid losing data type for the partitioned data when writing from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a dataframe like below.

```
itemName, itemCategory
Name1, C0
Name2, C1
Name3, C0
```

I would like to save this dataframe as partitioned parquet file:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("itemCategory").parquet(path)
```

For this dataframe, when I read the data back, it will have String the data type for `itemCategory`.

However at times, I have dataframe from other tenants as below.

```
itemName, itemCategory
Name1, 0
Name2, 1
Name3, 0
```

In this case, after being written as partition, when read back, the resulting dataframe will have Int for the data type of `itemCategory`.

Parquet file has the metadata that describe the data type. How can I specify the data type for the partition so it will be read back as String instead of Int?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that when you read in the "at other times" dataframes that it's getting read in as a CSV or a file format that requires the type to be inferred?

Comment: No, the files are in parquet format so data types are not infered except for the partition keys.

Answer (score 9):

If you set "spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled" to "false", spark will infer all partition columns as Strings.

In spark 2.0 or greater, you can set like this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
```

In 1.6, like this:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
```

The downside is you have to do this each time you read the data, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you partition by the `itemCategory` column, this data will be stored in the file structure and not in the actual csv files. Spark infer the datatype depending on the values, if all values are integers then the column type will be int.

One simple solution would be to cast the column to `StringType` after reading the data:

```
import spark.implicits._
df.withColumn("itemCategory", $"itemCategory".cast(StringType))
```

---

Another option would be to duplicate the column itself. Then one of the columns will be used for the partitioning and, hence, be saved in the file structure. However, the other duplicated column would be saved normally in the parquet file. To make a duplicate simply use:

```
df.withColumn("itemCategoryCopy", $"itemCategory")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I simplified the problem in the question. I have a generic parquet reader that reads file into dataframe by requested partition, so it will be quite a challenge to have to introduce this specific logic.

Comment: @suriyanto I see, I added an alternative solution that maybe could help you, although the solution is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Read it with a schema:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val path = "/tmp/test/input"
val source = Seq(("Name1", "0"), ("Name2", "1"), ("Name3", "0")).toDF("itemName", "itemCategory")
source.write.partitionBy("itemCategory").parquet(path)
spark.read.schema(source.schema).parquet(path).printSchema() 
// will print 
// root
// |-- itemName: string (nullable = true)
// |-- itemCategory: string (nullable = true)
```

See https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL2R2aXJ0ekBnbWFpbC5jb20vMzEzZGE2ZmZjZjY0NGRiZjk2MzdlZDE4NjEzOWJlZWYvbm90ZS5qc29u