# Partition column is moved to end of row when saving a file to Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

For a given DataFrame just before being `save`'d to `parquet` here is the schema: notice that the `centroid0` is the **first** column and is `StringType`:

[image]

However when saving the file using:

```
      df.write.partitionBy(dfHolder.metadata.partitionCols: _*).format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(fpath)
```

and with the `partitionCols` as `centroid0`:

[image]

then there is a (to me) surprising result:

- the `centroid0` partition column has been moved to the **end** of the Row
- the data type has been changed to `Integer`

I confirmed the output path via `println` :

```
 path=/git/block/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/data/output/blocking/out//level1/clusters
```

And here is the schema upon reading *back* from the saved `parquet`:

[image]

Why are those two modifications to the input schema occurring - and how can they be avoided - while still maintaining the `centroid0` as a partitioning column?

**Update**  A preferred answer should mention why /when the partitions were added to the *end* (vs the *beginning*) of the columns list. We need an understanding of the deterministic ordering.

In addition - is there any way to cause `spark` to "change it's mind" on the inferred column types?  I have had to change the partitions from `0`, `1` etc to `c0`, `c1` etc in order to get the inference to map to `StringType`. Maybe that were required .. but if there were some spark setting to change the behavior that would make for an excellent answer.

Comment: Maybe the answer here can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657954/avoid-losing-data-type-for-the-partitioned-data-when-writing-from-spark

Comment: @shaido But what about the **re-ordering** of the column to the end?

Comment: Since the information about the column is stored in the filestructure, Spark will not know what it's original position in the dataframe was. Adding it in the beginning or the end are the simplest solutions and it seems the end was chosen in the implementation here.

Comment: I have seen other dataframes using the same `partitionBy()` method (and with one or more partitioning columns) in which the columns were retained at the *front* (original positions). If you run into any further documentation/explanation that provide some deterministic means to understand the ordering pls do comment or add an answer.

Comment: I tried to check the source code but unfortunatly I couldn't find anything regarding why the partition column/columns are not consitently added to either the beginning or end. Regarding the column types, wouldn't it work to simply `cast` the type to string after reading (as in the link in my first comment).

Comment: `cast` will not work because the error occurs upon initial access via `spark.read.parquet`

Comment: What error? Also, have you tried supplying a schema when reading the parquet? It's possible it would solve both the order and the type problem.

Comment: `spark.read.parquet(paths: String*)` does not take/require a schema since the schema is built in to the dataset itself

Comment: try `spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(paths)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `write.partitionBy(...)` Spark saves the partition field(s) as folder(s)
This is can be beneficial for reading data later as (with some file types, parquet included) it can optimize to read data just from partitions that you use (i.e. if you'd read and filter for centroid0==1 spark wouldn't read the other partitions

The effect of this is that the partition fields (`centroid0` in your case) are not written into the parquet file only as folder names (`centroid0=1`, `centroid0=2`, etc.)

The side effect of these are 1. the type of the partition is inferred at run time (since the schema is not saved in the parquet) and in your case it happened that you only had integer values so it was inferred to integer.

The other side effect is that the partition field is added at the end/beginning of the schema as it reads the schema from the parquet files as one chunk and then it adds to that the partition field(s) as another (again, it is no longer part of the schema that is stored in the parquet)

Comment: Any idea why /when the partitions were added to the *beginning* vs the *end* of the columns list?  I need to understand  a deterministic ordering. thanks. I have updated the OP for a bit more on the info being sought.

Comment: you can always do a select with the columns in the order you'd like them to be and also cast to string just in case when reading the data. This is probably better anyway if the schema would evolve going forward to ensure this process has a fixed schema

Comment: Re-selecting is a non starter due to computational cost.

Comment: There's almost zero computational cost - it's a just a projection

Comment: That's not the case here since we're talking about directly after invoking `spark.read.parquet` : this will incur an additional full scan of the data. A full scan *is* costly for the datasets I work with.

Comment: no it wont - Spark will do the projection as it reads the data

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pretty easily make use of ordering of the columns of a case class that holds the schema of your partitioned data. You will need to read the data from the path, inside which the partitioning columns are stored underneath to make Spark infer the values of these columns. Then simply apply re-ordering by using the case class schema with a statement like:

```
val encoder: Encoder[RecordType] = Encoders.product[RecordType]
spark.read
      .schema(encoder.schema)
      .format("parquet")
      .option("mergeSchema", "true")
      .load(myPath)
      // reorder columns, since reading from partitioned data, the partitioning columns are put to end
      .select(encoder.schema.fieldNames.head, encoder.schema.fieldNames.tail: _*)
      .as[RecordType]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in fact pretty simple. When you partition by a column, each partition can only contain one value of the said column. Therefore it is useless to actually write the same value everywhere in the file, and this is why Spark does not. When the file is read, Spark uses the information contained in the names of the files to reconstruct the partitioning column and it is put at the end of the schema. The type of the column is not stored, it is inferred when reading, hence the integer type in your case. 
NB: There is no particular reason as to why the column is added at the end. It could have been at the beginning. I guess it is just an arbitrary choice of implementation.

To avoid losing the type and the order of the columns, you could duplicate the partitioning column like this `df.withColumn("X", 'YOUR_COLUMN).write.partitionBy("X").parquet("...")`.

You will waste space though. Also, spark uses the partitioning to optimize filters for instance. Don't forget to use the X column for filters after reading the data and not your column or Spark won't be able to perform any optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the OP for more specifics on what I am looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't a cast do the trick? `df.withColumn("centroid0", col("centroid0").cast("string")`

Comment: That will not work since the error occurs upon the initial read-back via `spark.read.parquet`