# How to order partitioned column to the beginning in Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition-by

I am having data which looks like this ,

```
1,IN,abc
2,US,pqr
3,UK,rst
4,IN,xyz
5,US,lmn
```

I am creating a dataframe over this data using spark-2.4.5 (scala)

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").load("file:///home/hduser/Desktop/demo.csv").toDF("id","country","name")
```

Now , When I am writing out data as a parquet file using following code ,

```
df.write.partitionBy("country").parquet("/ex_1/spark_parquet")
```

The output looks like this,

```
+---+----+-------+
| id|name|country|
+---+----+-------+
|  3| rst|     UK|
|  1| abc|     IN|
|  4| xyz|     IN|
|  2| pqr|     US|
|  5| lmn|     US|
+---+----+-------+
```

Currently, the partitioned column is at last location ,
is there any way using which I can achieve following output (with partitioning on "country" column)

The output should be in Parquet format

```
+-------+----+---+
|country|name| id|
+-------+----+---+
|     UK| rst|  3|
|     IN| abc|  1|
|     IN| xyz|  4|
|     US| pqr|  2|
|     US| lmn|  5|
+-------+----+---+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition column is moved to end of row when saving a file to Parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962934/partition-column-is-moved-to-end-of-row-when-saving-a-file-to-parquet)

Comment: Thank you for your response , the link you've shared answered few of my queries ,the question which i asked is very much similar to the one you shared , Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

1 - why partitioned column's location is last (Spark) :
you can check Chitral Verma comment's : [Partition column is moved to end of row when saving a file to Parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962934/partition-column-is-moved-to-end-of-row-when-saving-a-file-to-parquet)

2- if you want to "reorder" column, you can use `select` :

```
df.show()

+---+----+-------+
| id|name|country|
+---+----+-------+
|  3| rst|     uk|
|  1| abc|     IN|
|  4| xyz|     IN|
+---+----+-------+

val dataOrdoned =
  df.select(
    "country",
    "name",
    "id"
  )

dataOrdoned.show()

+-------+----+---+
|country|name| id|
+-------+----+---+
|     uk| rst|  3|
|     IN| abc|  1|
|     IN| xyz|  4|
+-------+----+---+
```

select is a transformation, so your output will have the same order than your dataset.

```
dataOrdoned.write.csv("path/country.csv")

uk,rst,3
IN,abc,1
IN,xyz,4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , And it is possible to select the data the way you've selected , my question is more about partitioning and the way partitioning works and is it possible to write output by changing the order of partitioned column

Comment: for partiting check Chitral comment. foy the second part of your comment, i have updated my answer

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right , however I need partitioned data in the output, and when we go for partitioning , column's location will change , I do need 'country' column at first location but I need data to be partitioned,